# Math notation to describe extending a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have vectors $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^2, \vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, how can I describe that $x$ is simply the concatenation of $y$ and $z$?

I want to convey that we take the elements of $\vec{y}$ and put them above the elements of $\vec{z}$ to get $\vec{x}$.

$\vec{x} = \vec{y} + \vec{z}$ is definitely wrong!

What's the terminology for this operation? extension or concatenation? Google really couldn't help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules

Comment: To amplify, we have a natural (linear) isomorphism of $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb R^2 \times \{(0,0)\} \subset \Bbb R^4$ that sends $y = (y_1,y_2) \mapsto (y_1,y_2,0,0) = \overline{y}$ and another similar isomorphism that maps $z = (z_1,z_2) \mapsto (0,0,z_1,z_2) = \overline{z}$, so that can write $x = \overline{y} + \overline{z}$

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a completely standard method of expressing this, but some things I have seen are $x = (y,z)$ (seeing $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product) of two copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $x=\begin{pmatrix} y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ (thinking in terms of [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), assuming each vector is written as a [column vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors)).

A nonstandard but suggestive notation could be $x = y\oplus z$, thinking of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of two copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I do not believe it is conventional to write elements of direct sums in this way, but it *is* conventional to do the perfectly analogous thing with [tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), so I'd make the case that it's a good notation.

(To be specific: in the category of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, tensor product is the [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct). If $X,Y$ are two $\mathbb{R}$-algebras, their tensor product is written $X\otimes Y$. As with all coproducts, $X$ and $Y$ each have a canonical map into $X\otimes Y$ and if $x\in X, y\in Y$, the product of the canonical images of $x,y$ in $X\times Y$ is written $x\otimes y$. Now translate this whole train of thought to the category of $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. In this category, direct sum is the coproduct. if $X,Y$ are two $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, then their direct sum is written $X\oplus Y$. $X$ and $Y$ both have canonical maps to $X\oplus Y$. The element of $X\oplus Y$ the OP wants a name for is the sum of the canonical images of $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ in $X\oplus Y$. In strict analogy with the tensor product case, why not call it $x\oplus y$?)